# Is there a way to tell the model number of a Mac or Macbook?

Tags: mac, macbook, macbook-pro, system-info

To upgrade memory (DRAM), the model of a Macbook Pro is needed for the website:

> http://www.crucial.com/index.aspx

but then there is no place that shows what the model number is, even from the `Apple -> About This Mac` from the menu bar.

(a model number is something like MB471LL/A )

(**Update**: the RAM is known to be DDR3, 1067GHz bus speed, but it is not known whether it supports 4GB or 8GB max for the upgrade to 8GB)

Since it is a company's computer, it is not sure it was purchased late 2008 or mid 2009...

Is there a way to find the model number some where from the computer?  There might be 10 Macbook Pro at the office so the manual and boxes probably is all mixed up by now...)

This is a Macbook Pro 15 inch unibody.

Answer (score 3):

Install [Mactracker](http://mactracker.dreamhosters.com/) and it will show you in lots of details what you need to find out. If it finds more than one match for your Mac, check it against the `System Profiler` (on the `About this Mac` window, click on `More`)

Answer (score 0):

Apple Menu -> About this Mac -> More Info

What *most* sites want for memory upgrade info is the Model Identifier, which is the second line down in the hardware overview. This is something like "MacBook2,1" or "iMac4,1". Unfortunately, Crucial's site doesn't do this.

RamJet's site -- http://www.ramjet.com/macbook.asp -- suggests that there are really only two choices for MBPs: 667 mhz / DDR2 or 1067 mhz DDR 3 RAM.  The Hardware Overview has a "Bus Speed" entry as well.